# Adding multiple images to Magento Products programmatically

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, shopping-cart

I have a magento site, my products are uploaded through a csv file. Now I need to update images for that products.
All of my images are downloaded an saved in my magento site media folder. I have created a csv file with 'SKU' and 'Absolute path' of image files.

Then I am trying to load that images with following code

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'Products/Vases/';
$file_handle = fopen("sku_image.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$num = count($data);
$row++;
$productSKU = $data[0];
$ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
for ($c=1; $c < $num; $c++) {
    $fileName = $data[$c];
    $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;
    if (file_exists($filePath)) {
        if ($ourProduct) {
            $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);
            $ourProduct->save();
        }
    } else {
        echo $productSKU . " not done";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Problem is that last image is set to all fields in product media attributes. How can I add images to different media attributes through above code.

---

I have changed my code as following

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->getStore()->setId(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'Products/Vases/';
$file_handle = fopen("sku_image.csv", "r");

while (($data = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    $productSKU = $data[0];

    $ourProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$productSKU);
    for ($c=1; $c<$num; $c++) {
        $fileName = $data[$c];
        $filePath = $importDir.$fileName;
        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
            if ($ourProduct) {
                if ($c==1) {
                     $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, 'rotator_image', false, false);
                } else {
                  $ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, null, false, false);

                }
                $ourProduct->save();
            }
        } else {
             echo $productSKU . " not done";
             echo "<br>";
        }

    }
    echo "<br>";

}
fclose($file_handle);
?>
```

Now my front site has been crashed. Cant load any products in my site.
Anyone have thoughts what I am missing ?

Comment: 'rotator_image' is a attribute in my attribute set 'images'

Comment: rotator_image, i don't think this works the way you think it does. Also your loop is suspect, you appear to be iterating over the columns with for for loop.

Comment: I have found the problem. If there is 3 image urls for any sku, the above code will add 5 images to that product. additional 2 images path are duplicated with a post under score 1 ('_1'). Which this new path have any valid file in the directory. That is why my site is being crashed. Any thoughts ?

Comment: Yes, you added an inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a because you are looping.

Every time you call `$ourProduct->addImageToMediaGallery($filePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), true, false);` the image, small_image & thumbnail are set to the new image that is added.

If you look at the comment on the function you are calling you will see this written out.

```
/**
 * Add image to media gallery
 *
 * @param string        $file              file path of image in file system
 * @param string|array  $mediaAttribute    code of attribute with type 'media_image',
 *                                          leave blank if image should be only in gallery
 * @param boolean       $move              if true, it will move source file
 * @param boolean       $exclude           mark image as disabled in product page view
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
 */
public function addImageToMediaGallery($file, $mediaAttribute=null, $move=false, $exclude=true)
```

So, if you want the first image to be the one used for the media attributes, you can add a check right before the call to *addImageToMediaGallery*. Then you either pass in null or the attribute(s) you wish to set.

The exact method you will need to use will depend on the setup of you csv file. Are the products in order, and other similar questions. Then you can figure out the exact check to use.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wish to know what is the difference between 'media gallery' and 'media attributes'

Comment: The short version is that the media gallery is the collection of images, and the media attributes is the choice of a specific image to be used for a specific attribute, (small_image, image, thumbnail)

Answer (score 0):

The best and the fastest way to import images for products is Magmi plugin. You have to place all your images under /media/import folder and simply in your csv create a columns named as sku small_image base_image and thumbnail.

And for the images column just enter the image path as /imagename.jpg

Make sure to enable the image attribute processor plugin enable in magmi. It will do the import in seconds. You can also import product images from urls also through magmi
http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor

Comment: I couldn't disagree more with this recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You add the additional images pro grammatically using the following script.

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-add-main-image-and-additional-image-to-the-products-pro-grammatically-magento/

```
$importDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
// additional images
    if ($import_product[29] != '') {
        $addImages = explode(",", trim($import_product[29]));
        foreach ($addImages as $additional_image) {
            $image_directory = $dir .DS.'data'.DS. trim($additional_image);
            if (file_exists($image_directory)) {
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
            } else {
                $image_directory = $dir . 'data' . DS . 'comingsoon.jpg';
                $product->addImageToMediaGallery($image_directory, null, false, false);
            }
        }
        echo 'Additional images for product ' . $product->getName() . ' ' . $product->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
    }
```